# visualsvn authentication bug, no author on commit

Tags: svn, permissions, visualsvn-server, author

I've got a Server where VisualSVN is running on. Its using HTTP protocol.

Everyone who is using the SVN-Client, connects with his Windows-authentication.

**My Problem is that my permissions (which I've set in the VisualSVN Server Manager) doesn't take effect.**

Everyone has the rights to Read/Write, doesn't matter that they are only Read.

The Author of the Commit is Noone (Emtpty), but if you've got rights(RW) you are the Author.

I can't remember that i have changed anything which could be the problem

Thanks in anticipation!

Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you made any customization of VisualSVN Server? Please make sure that %VISUALSVN_SERVER%\conf\httpd-custom.conf is empty.

Comment: I only made a customizsation for Trac, but its independent to svn :/

Comment: I think Trac customization can cause such problems. I recommend you to disable Trac and try to reproduce problem. Please report this issue to VisualSVN Support Team if disabling Trac doesn't help.

Comment: Ive ever used VisualSVN in connection with Trac and i never had problems with the authentication, i will try to reproduce it, thanks.

Comment: Okay, i disabled my Custom-Config for Trac, it doesnt help, im Just linking to Trac with given AuthenticationGroups, my VisualSVN is listening on 8443 and is permamently redirected to svn:443, i just ask myself why my TortoiseSVN client is not asking for my Authentication after I have cleaned my AuthenticationCache.

Answer (score 0):

> Everyone has the rights to Read/Write, doesn't matter that they are only Read.

In VisualSVN's, unless something else is explicitly specified, all repositories inherit the default rights settings. My guess is your problem is here.

Try removing "everyone"'s right to read/write in the default settings. I'm pretty sure that will help.

Comment: I havent defined any default Rights manually, Ive got my SVN-Repo and added some users with specified permissions to the Repo-Properties Some are Read, some are Read/Write, and the Read-Ones are also allowed to Write "anonymously"

Comment: @a.schwab VisualSVN brings default settings along automatically. Are you 100% sure you have no "everyone" setting that is set to "read/write"?

Comment: I definitely have no everyone settings on my Repo, and my RootDir (called Repositories) has no rights to anyone.